# Difference between bound and unbound cursor in pgsql:

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

I need to know the difference between a bound cursor and an unbound cursor and please tell me also how to open a bound and an unbound cursor in PL/pgSQL. The documentation given by pgsql website is not that clear and understandable.

Comment: [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-DECLARATIONS) seems pretty clear. There is one chapter [dedicated to opening an unbound cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#id-1.8.8.9.5.4) and another one titled [Opening a Bound Cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#id-1.8.8.9.5.5)

Answer (score 1):

Consider it a variable of type refcursor which has not been initialized to point to anything yet. A bound cursor is a variable of type refcursor which can only be used with the query that it has been initialized to. Unbound cursors can be used with any query in the future.

Answer (score 0):

All access to cursors goes through cursor variables, which are always of the special data type refcursor

One way to create a cursor variable is just to declare it as a variable of type refcursor.

```
curs1 refcursor;
```

this can be used with any query, therefore it is known as unbound cursor.

Another way is to use the cursor declaration syntax, which in general is:

```
CURSOR <cursor_name> IS <SELECT stmt>
```

This cursor is bound to the particular query so it is known as bound cursor.